# JavaScript code error with basic program (Guessing game)

Tags: javascript

When I run the program, it will never display the alert (the first `if` statement), even if I did guess the correct number. I could also use some help on how to loop the program 5 times, I tried a `for` loop with little success.

---

```
var rdmNumber = Math.random(); 
var timesNumber = rdmNumber * 10;
var theNumber = Math.round(timesNumber);
var userInput = prompt("Take a Guess (0-10)");
if(userInput === theNumber) {
    alert("You Guessed it! " + userInput + " is correct");
} else if(userInput === theNumber.toString()) {
    console.log("Higher");
} else {
    console.log("Lower");
}
console.log(theNumber);
```

Comment: `userImput` is a string, while `theNumber` is a number. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/1048572

Comment: And a basic for loop around the `userImput` should handle your looping for 5 guesses of `theNumber`

Answer (score 1):

### thanks everyone, i figured out my own solution but really appreceate the feedback, this site has a great community. here is the working result

```
var rdmNumber = Math.random(); 
var timesNumber = rdmNumber * 10;
var theNumber = Math.round(timesNumber);
while (userInput != theNumber) {
var userInput = prompt("Take a Guess (0-10)");
if(userInput == theNumber) {
  alert("You Guessed it! " + userInput + " is correct");
}
   else if(userInput < theNumber) {
    alert("Higher");
  } 
else {
 alert("Lower");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Bergi already mentioned, userImput is a string and theNumber is an integer. What you can do is use parseInt function to convert userImput to integer like so: `var userImput = parseInt(prompt("Take a Guess (0-10)")) ;`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a long time.  The `prompt` function returns a string.  you need to use `parseInt()` to convert that string to a number in order to do math or comparisons with it.

Here's the corrected code:

```
var rdmNumber = Math.random(); 
   var timesNumber = rdmNumber * 10;
   var theNumber = Math.round(timesNumber);
   var userImput = parseInt(prompt("Take a Guess (0-10)"));
   if(userImput === theNumber) {
   alert("You Guessed it! " + userImput + " is correct");
   }
   else if(userImput === theNumber) {
   console.log("Higher");
    } 
    else {
    console.log("Lower");
    }
    console.log(theNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

declare it in a function like this:

```
function guessingGame() {
    var rdmNumber = Math.random(); 
    var timesNumber = rdmNumber * 10;
    var theNumber = Math.round(timesNumber);
    var userInput = prompt("Take a Guess (0-10)");
    if(userInput === theNumber) {
        alert("You Guessed it! " + userInput + " is correct");
    } else if(userInput === theNumber.toString()) {
        console.log("Higher");
    } else {
        console.log("Lower");
    }
    console.log(theNumber);
}
```

and call it in your program like this:

```
var i=0;
while (i < 5) {
    guessingGame();
    i++;
}
```